# App getting Crash while Playing youtube video using Youtube Data API in Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin.android

While playing the video on mobile app getting crash and throwing below exception

```
Xamarin caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method "Lcom/google/android/youtube/player/internal/s;.setPlayerStyle(Lcom/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer$PlayerStyle;)V"
    at md5591aee671cd921079ff639ee236e4572.YoutubeActivity.n_onInitializationSuccess(Native Method)
    at md5591aee671cd921079ff639ee236e4572.YoutubeActivity.onInitializationSuccess(YoutubeActivity.java:56)
    at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView$1.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r.g(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$c.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$b.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$a.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7331)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: you have to write at least something. Please see [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: @Thatkookooguy thanx for your suggestion